# Marketing Cloud - callout from CloudPage to MC API - where to store credentials

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, security, cloudpage

We are building a simple functionality on a CloudPage that will be making an API call to Marketing Clouds API. I was looking at documentation to find information on where we should store the Client Id and secret, but only found the following:

> Store your client ID and secret securely. Never expose this information on the client side via JavaScript or store it in a mobile application.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm

So where and how should we store it to make sure it’s safe?
All suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at named credentials (
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secure-secret-storage/learn-about-platform-secret-protection)

Comment: @Cleverlemming - Is this also for MC? Assuming this only works for Core?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's for logging in from Sales Cloud. The posted ampscript solution is a better choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a bullet proof solution, but I have implemented an increased level of security by using [EncryptSymmetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm) and [DecryptSymmetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DecryptSymmetric.htm), so you avoid storing the id and secret directly in Ampscript.

First you create the three required assets in [Key Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_key_management.htm&type=5):

- Password
- Salt
- Initialisation vector

You need to use the EncryptSymmetric in a different Cloud Page to get the encrypted value, which you can use in your integration. This can then be stored in e.g. @APIsecretEncrypted value, without exposing it in clear text. Use same password, salt and initialisation vector to decrypt it:

```
SET @APIsecret = DecryptSymmetric(@APIsecretEncrypted, "AES", "passwordExternalKey", @null, "saltExternalKey", @null, "IVExternalKey", @null)
```

Again, this is by no means high security, as anyone can ask @APIsecret to be printed: `%%=V(@APIsecret)=%%` hereby exposing it. But it at least gives you additional level of "hiding" it.

Comment: Thank you - so I hardcode the encrypted values directly in the CloudPage and decrypt them in ampscript before I make the call?

Comment: Yes, indeed @julia2019

Comment: @LukasLunow, what do you mean by "anyone can ask APIsecret to be printed" ? AmpScript runs server side, so to print a variable one mist have access to edit the Cloud page, or what am I missing?

Comment: @LimeWeb you are correct. You do need edit access to change your Ampscript and show the values. My point is, that anyone with access to MC can potentially use this method to familiarise himself with the credentials, making unauthorised use of the secured resource possible outside of SFMC.

Comment: Also, @LukasLunow what about the option to either use field level encryption to store the encrypted password in a DE? Would that work? Or encrypt it manually and store the encrypted value?
Then let AmpScript read the DE and decrypt as you describe. If this is possible it's still not bulletproof, but seems as secure as your suggestion, so putting alternatives out there. Thoughts? Eventually store the DE in another BU different from the Ampscript Cloudpage

Comment: @LimeWeb the main problem is, that you will need to use it in plain text/decrypted, when authenticating the API call. As long as this is the case, anyone will be able to access it in an Ampscript variable and read it.

Comment: @LukasLunow, agreed. To add another level of security to your solution - My suggestion would be to have a very access-restricted Admin BU to actually make the authentication calls in order to retrieve the accessToken. Only 100% trusted users (Super admins) should have access to this BU - and so to AmpScript in this BU. The Admin BU will only store the refreshed AccessTokens in a shared DE. The BU that needs to call the API will then first call the AmpScript in the Admin BU to refresh the token, without exposing the password, then read the temporary AccessToken to proceed.

Comment: The only way to get a hand on the Password would then be to compromise the Admin BU users.

Comment: @LukasLunow - do you have a suggestion on how to adapt this solution for a script activity which does not support AMPscript?

Comment: @AntonioDePalma - did you try googling "decrypt symmetric SSJS" :-) ? This will return this URL as one of the top results: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281796/ssjs-equivalent-of-decryptsymmetric